# Template deduction does not work with std::endl?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'd like to wrap cerr and cout inside an object that intentionally throws away everything in the release build. The intention is to make sure that some debug outputs that a developer might have forgotten to remove will not be shown to the user.

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper( std::ostream& os ):mOs(os){}

    template <typename T>
    DebugOnlyOsWrapper&
    operator<<( T&& in ){
        #ifndef NDEBUG
            mOs << std::forward<T>(in);
        #endif
        return *this;           
    }

private:
    std::ostream& mOs;
};


extern DebugOnlyOsWrapper dcout;   
extern DebugOnlyOsWrapper dcerr;
```

However, I'm getting a "couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'" error when calling the operator as follows:

```
dcerr << std::endl;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to deduce type from a function pointer?

Note that adding the following operator overloads fixes the problem, however I'd like to limit code duplication as well as understand the nature of the problem.

```
using CharT = std::ostream::char_type;   
using Traits = std::ostream::traits_type;

Wrapper& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) ){
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        mOs << func;
    #endif
    return *this;           
}
Wrapper& operator<<(
        std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& 
            (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) 
){
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        mOs << func;
    #endif
    return *this;           
}
Wrapper& operator<<(
        std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& 
            (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) 
){
    #ifndef NDEBUG
        mOs << func;
    #endif
    return *this;           
}
```

Thank you

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427695/using-stream-operator-with-stdendl-in-c

Comment: Duplicate, possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170934/enable-template-only-if-the-return-expression-is-valid/51171146

Comment: I would say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170934/enable-template-only-if-the-return-expression-is-valid/51171146 leads ultimately to the same problem, but the question is different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `std::endl` is not a function but a template.

If the following overload exists, the templates of std::endl are deduced within the call of this overload and hence it works.

```
Wrapper& operator<<(
        std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& 
            (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) 
);
```

On the other hand the generic template does not contain enough information to resolve the template parameters of `std::endl`.

Hence finally, I decided to use something like this:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper( std::ostream& os ):mOs(os){}

    using CharT = std::ostream::char_type;
    using Traits = std::ostream::traits_type;

    template <typename T>
    Wrapper&
    operator<<( T&& in ){
        return impl(std::forward<T>(in));
    }

    DebugOnlyOsWrapper& operator<<(
            std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& 
                (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) 
    ){
        return impl(func);
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    DebugOnlyOsWrapper& impl( T&& in ){
        #ifndef NDEBUG
            mOs << std::forward<T>(in);
        #endif
        return *this;           
    }
    std::ostream& mOs;
};
```

Comment: Fascinating. I could have sworn the same explanation is given in the answers to the question I suggested as a duplicate.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, I agree, the answer is the same, but the question is not the same IMO.